# Only config.php file is not getting from folder in specific PHP version 5.5.28

Tags: php, include, version

This is my folder structure.

[image]

**Problem Description**

I have included **inner.php** file of **inc** folder at **index.php**.
Then I have included **config.php** file of **inc** folder at inner.php file.

When i run index.php url in browser then output show like below image.
[image]

That output only shows "inner". That means data of config file is not displayed.

Solution can be got by the use of magic constant like **__DIR__, __FILE__**.

But i need to understand why this problem is created when file name is **config.php**.

Because when i change file name from **config.php** to **config2.php** then browser shows content of **config2.php** file.

See below code and output image.

Code file image

[image]

Output display image

[image]

Output shows "configinner" means data print of config file.

According above scenario you can see when i have included **config2.php** file then it has been included properly.

So that means **config.php** name file is always get from main route and it not take from inner folder at especially in PHP version 5.5.28.

Am i right or not?

Comment: First, let me say you should not be running anything below PHP 5.6 (even 5.6 is deprecated). That said, it is not the case in PHP 7.2; I created the same structure and everything worked fine.

Comment: @Samuel I know that this thing is working properly in PHP 7.2. But i want to know the valid reason why the config.php file is not included in PHP version 5.5.28.
Can you check in specific version (5.5.28) please?

Answer (score 0):

`index.php` is not in the `inc` folder.

In order to include it, you need to include it like this:

```
include "inc/config.php"
```

`config2.php` is added via require if you use `include`, it would behave in the same manner.

Comment: you are right but can you solve My confusion that when i run this code `include "config2.php"` that runs perfectly then why this code `include "config.php"`
is not working. Can you explain me this issue?

Comment: My means only name of config.php file is not getting in my scenario when i update the file name with config2.php then it included and run properly without provide the full path of that inc folder. Can you understand my problem? You can do this demo in PHP 5.5.28 version and identify this issue.